# Error dividing by zero

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I am trying to calculate the implied vol but because my variable T is under 0.1 I am getting this strange error. "divide by zero encountered in double_scalars"
I would like to know what I am doing wrong.  Thanks.

```
#Importamos librerias
from math import log,exp,sqrt
from scipy import stats
#Definimos nuestra funcion acumulativa 
N = stats.norm.cdf

#Definimos la formula de Black Scholes para una opción Call
def BS(S0,K,T,r,sigma):
    S0 = float(S0)
    d1 = (log(S0/K)+(r + 0.5 * sigma**2)*T)/(sigma*sqrt(T))
    d2 = (log(S0/K)+(r - 0.5*sigma**2)*T)/(sigma*sqrt(T))
    value = (S0*N(d1)-K*exp(-r*T)*N(d2))
    return value


#Definimos Vega que es la derivada con respecto de sigma
def Vega(S0,K,T,r,sigma):
    S0 = float(S0)
    d1 = (log(S0/K)+(r + 0.5 * sigma**2)*T)/(sigma*sqrt(T))
    vega = S0 * N(d1)*sqrt(T)
    return vega

#Definimos la volatilidad implicita usando BS y Vega, usamos el metodo de 
#Newton para resolver
def ImpliedVol(S0, K, T, r, C0, sigma_est, it=100):
    for i in range(it):
        sigma_est -= ((BS(S0,K,T,r, sigma_est)-C0)/Vega(S0,K,T,r,sigma_est))
    return sigma_est

#Calculamos de Acuerdo a los parametros

S0 = 173
K = 130
T = 0.02
r = 0.029
C0 = 42
Sigma_init = 0.5

print(ImpliedVol(S0,K,T,r,C0,Sigma_init))
```

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: is in this line:  sigma_est -= ((BS(S0, K, T, r, sigma_est) - C0) / Vega(S0, K, T, r, sigma_est))

Comment: can you print out what `Vega(S0, K, T, r, sigma_est)` returns?

Comment: yes, I am able to print it out

Comment: What does it give you?

Comment: a float with a value of 24 or something like that I am changing the parameters and running more test.

Comment: My best guess it that at some point Vega returns 0, so it crashes because of the division.

Comment: Well, you constantly subtract something from the initial `sigma_est`. After 13 loops it becomes negative, therefore `d1` becomes negative, therefore `N(d1)` is zero, therefore `vega` is zero, therefore you divide the right side by zero. This is descriptive and you should have found out about it by placing a print into each loop. What it means, only you can know, because you didn't explain properly, what your code does.